# How to extract the contents in html tag <body> in JEditorPane and append it to the <body> of another JEditorPane?

Tags: html, string, append, extract, jeditorpane

I have a 2 JEditorPane(s). I want to take the text from the body of one JEditorPane and append it to another JEditorPane. The printout from the first JEditorPane using .getText() is:

```
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
    Here is some <b>bold text</b>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to get the whole string in the body including the bold tags

Comment: this event is triggered when user press a button..

Answer (score 1):

```
String out = outgoingMsg.getText().replaceAll("</*html>|</*head>|</*body>|\n|\r", "");
    out = out.trim();
```

This will remove html,head,body opening and closing tags as well as unnecessary new lines and leading and trailing whitespaces.